# Can a question be made on-topic by hiding the real reason the OP is asking it?

Tags: discussion

If [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/154420/lightning-strikes-causing-nudity) had been worded like this:

"Is it physically plausible that a lightning strike could make your sweat boil and cause your clothes to explode off your body"

would it still have been closed?

Comment: I think the answer to the general question is a resounding "yes", and that this isn't really a problem.

Comment: But closing questions is fun!

Comment: @SeanD: The fact that that's funny to you hurts me right in the physics.

Comment: @DanielSank I think overzealous editing is a "big problem" (see: Wikipedia) and it hurts me to see it too.

Comment: What is meant by "OP"?

Comment: @Sushant23: It means "original post" or "person who made the original post".

Comment: This question seems more appropriate on https://what-if.xkcd.com/ and I'd actually be interested in reading the article there.

Comment: A plane crash can leave you naked. Survivors of the first autopilot had their 'clothes divested by the force of the crash' hahaha http://john.hultgren.org/trivia/mile_high_club.html

Answer (score 12):

The problem with questions like this is that they're like asking *can an elephant fly?* The answer is yes if you're allowed to start at the top of a cliff and your definition of *flight* includes trajectories normal to the ground.

The point is that the question is not answerable from first principles in any useful way. You might say yes your clothes could be blown off if you were coated in a continuous film of sweat with a high enough conductivity and there was enough power in the lightning to vaporise all the sweat and your clothes were impermeable enough for a high pressure to be built up. But that doesn't tell us anything useful, hedged around as it is with numerous conditions.

The way to approach the question would be to examine actual lightning strikes to try and establish whether the phenomenon happened, and if so what factors were common to all occurrences. At this point it might be useful to approach a physicist and try to model the specific phenomena involved.

So I think Kyle's response is spot on. Post on the Skeptics SE in the hope someone can point you to the sort of evidence mentioned above. As it stands the question isn't appropriate here.

Comment: Indeed, as it stands it't not appropriate. The problem (again) is that the close reason does not actually say what is wrong with the post and, more importantly, it does not give the author a hint as to how to fix it.

Comment: Wait, do normal humans not define flight that way?

Comment: @DanielSank well, in cases that don't clearly fall under one of the standard close reasons, a bit of interaction in the comments is often necessary to explain why the post is off topic and how (and if) it can be made on topic. I don't think that's such a bad thing.

Comment: "trajectories normal to the ground" Hahaha!

Comment: @Jim 'normal' means a 90 degree angle, so by "normal to the ground" John means straight down.

Comment: @Jim apologies for misunderstanding.

Comment: Re: "The point is that the question is not answerable from first principles in any useful way [...]". I think it would be very interesting to see *how* to calculate something like this. I'd have no idea where to start. This has potential for a great answer, a la: "A typical lighting strike has a current of such-and-such, looked up [here]. Then you can model the person as a hollow tube of sweat and neglect the body itself. Heating of a liquid by a current is described by $f(x)$, but you have cooling by evaporation $g(x)$, and then you can calculate the force per area with $h(x)$".

Comment: @jdm: Hear hear!